# How to highlight current cursor values on X and Y axis in plotly?

Tags: python-3.x, plot, plotly, plotly-python

I have a plotly chart and whenever I move cursor on it, I want to see corresponding X and Y values being highlighted. How can I achieve that? Below is sample image of how it should look.

[image]
(Not a very clear image, but on Y-axis you can see highlighted tickers)

Here's a sample code for a simple plotly plot

```py
import datetime as dt
import panel as pn
import yfinance as yf

pn.extension()

# Data part
vix_tickers = ['AUDJPY=X']

df = yf.download(vix_tickers,
                 auto_adjust=True, #only download adjusted data
                 progress=False,
            )
df = df[["Close"]]

# A Plot
import plotly.graph_objs as go

fig = go.Figure()
df.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=True)

trace = go.Scatter(x=list(df.index), y=list(df.Close))
fig.add_trace(trace)

fig.update_layout(
    dict(
        title="Time series with range slider and selectors",
        xaxis=dict(
            rangeselector=dict(
                buttons=list(
                    [
                        dict(count=1, label="1m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
                        dict(count=6, label="6m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
                        dict(count=1, label="YTD", step="year", stepmode="todate"),
                        dict(count=1, label="1y", step="year", stepmode="backward"),
                        dict(step="all"),
                    ]
                )
            ),
            rangeslider=dict(visible=False),
            type="date",
        ),
    )
)
fig.show()
```